# file_get_contents() issues related to my SMS API intrigation

Tags: file-get-contents

`file_get_contents(http://smshorizon.co.in/api/sendsms.php?user=***&apikey=******&mobile=*****&message=Hello World&senderid=xxyy&type=txt)`

Here in this SMS API when I use a message with space say "Hello World" then it return `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`. But when I remove the space and instead I write HelloWorld it works fine.

What is the issue?

Comment: Did you try to use url encode ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Yes I have solved the problem by using str_replace the space with "%20"

Answer (score 0):

Why its happening (Problem):

URL is getting spitted because of **space between messages** and it will consider only part before space.

Solution:

You can use PHP inbuilt **function urlencode()**;

```
 Input : urlencode('Hello World');
 Output : urlencode('Hello%20World');
```